# When is the ed in blessed pronounced as /id/ or /t/?

Tags: pronunciation

When is the ed in blessed pronounced as /id/ or /t/?

I found id as an adjective before a noun. Eg. Have a blessed day. The blessed vergin Mary. And May you have a blessed holiday.

I found blessed /t/ in feel blessed. Islands of the blessed.

But /id/ in "The blessed in the heavenly kingdom "

As a verb as in They blessed us and we were blessed, I think it's /t/

Sources forvo and Cambridge dictionary

Can someone shed a light on this?

Comment: It's the same with ***learned*** - when used as a past tense verb, ***learned*** (spelt ***learnt*** in British English; *We learnt how to do long division in school today*) is a single syllable word. But when used as an ***adjective*** (as in *He is a learned scholar*) it's two syllables. See [comments here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558692/why-can-t-i-turn-fast-paced-into-a-quality-noun-by-adding-the-ness-suf%EF%AC%81x#comment1378949_558734) about "Upstart Crow" making fun of speakers inappropriately enunciating that final syllable. And opinions still differ today! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the past tense or past participle of the verb "bless" it is pronuned "blest", as an adjective (meaning "revered, holy" and in Catholicism "beatified") it is "blesid".

In some situations both the adjective and the particple can be used, and there is quite a lot of variation.

So "The islands of the blessed" is a counterpart to "... of the dammed", and the pronunciation seems likely to reflect euphony as much as meaning.

And "I feel blessed" is the participle, you could add a "by God" giving the subject of the verb.